# Altium "Update PCB documents", components are generated at the same place

Tags: altium

I'm new with hierchical design in Altium. When I update the PCB, all the components of the multi sheets are generated at the same place.

There is the hiearchy of the project :

### [image]

I highlighted the problematic sheets in yellow!

- There is two "InputAmplifier" sheets in "InputConnectors"
- There is eight "InputsConnectors" sheets in "AudioInputs_16"
- There is one "AudioInputs" sheet in "TopLevel"
- There is eight "OutputConnectors" sheets in "AudioOutputs_16"
- There is one "AudioOutput" sheet in "TopLevel"

The components are looking like this on the PCB:

[image]

-

And far away all the components of the problematic sheets are generated at the same point:
[image]

How can I split all the components? There is a lot of components and moving all of them by hand will be really long.

Thank you!

Comment: Try this: click the room, then: Tools > Component Placement > Arrange within Room. (t >o > r)

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is to arrange the parts per section of the schematic, regardless of hierarchical structure, so what in your case would be a single input amplifier within the input connector page.

To do that, you just type T O L  or click on the tools menu, Component placement and Arrange within rectangle. Then you just draw a rectangle with the cursor of the mouse, where you want your parts to be.